# equality of a series to its limit at infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number because there are no $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{a}{b} = \sqrt{2}$. However you can get arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{2}$ with rational fractions. So there are series' the limit of which is $\sqrt{2}$, but they do not converge on $\sqrt{2}$ because the rational numbers are incomplete and $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number as mentioned above. An infinite continued fraction or infinite series that approaches $\sqrt{2}$ will be actually equal to $\sqrt{2}$, if however you take a series that approaches $\sqrt{2}$ monotonously from below and interrupt it at some point you will have a fraction that is strictly less than $\sqrt{2}$.

Ok, now to my actual problem, say you have a set $\{ n \in \mathbb{Q} | n^2 < 2\}$. Now... what then is the supremum of this set? It says $n^2 < 2$ and not $n^2 \leq 2$ It cannot be a series of rational fractions whose limit is $\sqrt{2}$, like $\prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4k+2)^2}{(4k +1)(4k +3)} = \sqrt{2}$ as that series actually IS $\sqrt{2}$ as it goes to infinity. So it has to be a series that approaches $\sqrt{2}$, gets arbitrarily close but also does not become equal to $\sqrt{2}$ as it goes to infinity. That does not sound possible to me.

As you can guess this is an exercise I am given, and I am wondering whether it is worded incorrectly and the $<$ should rather be a $\leq$ or if I am fundamentally misunderstanding something about limit behavior and equality of an expression to its limit as it approaches infinity.

tl;dr: can there be a series that gets arbitrarily close to its limit but does not become *equal* to it at infinity?

Comment: What is the exercise exactly?

Comment: @GitGud find the supremum of $\{ n \in \mathbb{Q} | n^2 < 2\}$

Comment: As a subset of $\Bbb Q$ or of $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: of $\mathbb{R}$ but what does that change of all $n$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Even for bounded sets of real numbers, the supremum need not be an element of the set (as this example shows).

Comment: @lulu why is that? The set definition says all elements need to be rational numbers... ?

Comment: So, ok...all the elements are rational.  Still doesn't mean the supremum is in the set (nor that it is rational).  For a simple example, take $\{-\frac 1n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.  That is bounded on both sides, and obviously all elements are rational.  The infimum, $-1$, is in the set.  The supremum $0$ is not (though it happens to be rational).

Comment: @lulu Ok, in that case $\{ n \in \mathbb{Q} | n^2 < 2\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ would be the exact same set as $\{ n \in \mathbb{Q} | n^2  \leq 2\} \subset \mathbb{R}$? Though I don't yet see the importance of the $\subset \mathbb{R}$ part as opposed to $\subset \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: That's correct. (the bit about the sets).  Incorrect about infimum and supremum.  See the examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) for instance.

Comment: I see, that clears it up. Thanks a lot.